# Printing String Values after Splitting in Angular .net Project

Tags: .net, angular, typescript, split, webapi

I'm trying to print a string value as string array after splitting the value by comma. I wanted to print the value after getting separated. I've used .net for web api, angular for Frontend.

**Below is the WebAPI Get method that I've used to get all the data from backend.**

```
[HttpGet("GetAllJobPostings")]
public IEnumerable<JobPosting> GetDetails(){
  return Context.JobPosting.ToList();
}
```

**This is the Model Class of JobPosting**

```js
export class JobPosting{
  jobid:number=0;
  title:string='';
  hrId:number=0;
  experience:number=0;
  position:string='';
  company:string='';
  ctc:number=0;
  skills:string='';
  description:string='';
}
```

**This is the method I'm using in my typescript file**

```js
allJobDetais:JobPosting[]=[];
allSkills:Array<String>=[];
constructor(private service:UserServiceService){}

ngOnInit(): void {
    
  this.postAllJobDetails();
  //console.log(this.allJobDetais);
}

//Current User
currentUser=this.service.loadCurrentUser()?.UserName;

postAllJobDetails()
{
  this.service.getAllJobPostings().subscribe((res:JobPosting[])=>{
    this.allJobDetais=res;
  });
}
```

**This is how I want my data to show**
[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CvF2H.png)

**This is the form by which I'm passing the value(a sample value as demo)**
Note : the value i'm passing in the skill field , storing as a string value not any type of array value
[Form Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8HZW.png)

**Request you to please help me with code that how can i split the value after getting by api and then show it in my html**